# Press-and-hold right-click conflicts with Manipulation events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using the `Manipulation` events (`IsManipulationEnabled`, `ManipulationDelta`, etc) to move and zoom an image. This works fine. I also want to use right-click to create a rectangle of selection to define a zone (drag and drop, the usual way, only with right-click) on the image. It works fine using the mouse on both touch (Surface) and non-touch (Win 7) devices. Though, when "right-clicking" on the Surface (therefore tap and hold with a finger), I see the typical little square appearing, but when I move my finger after that, it moves the image, instead of drawing the rectangle. It looks as if the `Manipulation` events have priority over the "finger right click". What am I doing wrong ?

```
 <Grid
    Name="theGrid"
    MouseMove="OnMouseMove"
    MouseRightButtonUp="theGrid_MouseRightButtonUp"
    MouseRightButtonDown="theGrid_MouseRightButtonDown"
    Background="Black">

    <Rectangle Name="RectangleContainingBackgroundImage"
               IsManipulationEnabled="True"
               RenderTransform="{Binding Path=ImageTransform}">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="BackgroundImage" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

At start :

```
ScreenTouchManager touchManager = new ScreenTouchManager(this.theGrid);
this.RectangleContainingBackgroundImage.ManipulationStarting += touchManager.Image_ManipulationStarting;
this.RectangleContainingBackgroundImage.ManipulationDelta += touchManager.Image_ManipulationDelta;
this.DataContext = touchManager;
```

In ScreenTouchManager :

```
public void Image_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    // Ask for manipulations to be reported relative to the grid
    e.ManipulationContainer = this.ManipContainer; // MC = constructor param
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have several manipulation containers in my window, and when I press-and-hold outside these containers, the right-click works fine. [This article](http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html) sheds insight on touch events vs. click events wrt manipulation.

Comment: Didn't find a solution, sorry :(. Also, now I don't have access anymore to the Surface, so I can't test anything, but if you find something that could have worked, please post. Obviously I won't be able to accept the answer, but I would be curious to see what was wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use a touchpoint on a corner of the screen because I couldn't get the press-and-hold to cooperate with the manipulation events.

Answer (score -1):

I did a research and may find a answer here: http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1396&lang=en

> The VisualState changes are triggered by dedicated mouse events: For
>   example, the Pressed state is reached when the button’s
>   OnMouseLeftButtonDown event occurs. The finger touch-and-hold event is
>   usually mapped to a click with the right mouse button (when tapping on
>   the screen and not instantly releasing the finger, Windows interprets
>   this as right-click operation) – the OnMouseLeftButtonDown event never
>   fires, and the Pressed state is never reached!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really :/  
Here, their problem is that the leftButton event isn't fired on a long touch because long touch = right-click (which must thus be disabled).
My problem, if anything, looks like the opposite. I WANT right-click, which looks enabled (it works if I start my right-click selection on a child element, like a button).

Comment: I want both left-click(<=>tap)+drag (to move the image), and right-click(<=>tap-and-hold)+drag (to make my selection rectangle). And they look a lot alike...
Anything unclear ?